# Truecaller isn't working if I change the Package Name of the App

Tags: flutter, dart

I developed an App with package for example - com.google.xyz deployed to playstore but due to some issues i had to create new App & i created as com.example.x_y_z

Now play store isn't accepting example. So I tried changing the package name in -

1. Build.gradle
2. 3 Android manifest files
3. Main activity.kt
4. Firebase json file
5. Truecaller API - Changed the package name but used the old SHA1 key.

Let me know what might be the issue? And how to solve this.

Thanks Alot

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, what does playstore give you the message on upload?

Comment: Main thing -

At first, I created a project and it's package name was com.google.wiki_app & it has no truecaller sdk. I deployed it to play store. Due to some issues with Firebase, had to take down

Then, my friend created a new project with new package name as com.example.wiki_app. In this, he used Truecaller Sdk. When I uploaded the Bundle to play store, it displayed error "Package name should be same & Example isn't allowed as package name". Then I changed the package name to com.google.wiki_app in App. Tried release app in phone but Truecaller didn't work.

Any Ideas? How to Solve?